# yo angular error after package.json

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I am trying to install angular on my windows 10. I followed every step in the yo tutorial, but once I get to package.json everything fails and shows errors. can anyone help me figuring out how to solve this. I have tried for almost a week searching online and nothing has worked. Error shown bellow:

```
*? Overwrite package.json? overwrite
    force     package.json
identical     .travis.yml
bower ENOGIT        git is not installed or not in the PATH
> phantomjs@1.9.17 install C:\Users\carli\node_modules\phantomjs
> node install.js
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)
Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:
http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
> phantomjs@1.9.17 install C:\Users\carli\node_modules\phantomjs
> node install.js
module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\carli\node_modules\phantomjs\install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\carli\\AppDat
Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! phantomjs@1.9.17 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs@1.9.17 install script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\carli\npm-debug.log
module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\carli\node_modules\phantomjs\install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\carli\\AppDat
Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! phantomjs@1.9.17 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs@1.9.17 install script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\carli\npm-debug.log*
```

I am trying to learn about Angularjs and this is one of the steps that is holding me back

Comment: do you have npm,bower, grunt installed on your device? try doing npm install -g grunt-cli if you dont

Comment: Error message also says you don't have git installed or that it's not in your path. So, uh, install that too if you don't already have it installed. And make sure it's in your path if it's not already in your path.

Comment: Jony-Y:I have all of them installed.                                                         Trott: i also installed git. didn't check path. i will let you know later if adding the path worked

Comment: Trott: sorry for late response. yes, it worked as you said the path was the issue. thank you